# What is the status of VAERS?

Tags: openfda

What is the status of the US government [Vaccine Averse Event Reporting System](https://vaers.hhs.gov/) (VAERS)?

Is there also a JSON file containing links to all downloadable files for automating the download of the data?

Comment: what do you mean by status?

Comment: whats the connection between vaers and openfda? is this data via vaers not good enough? https://vaers.hhs.gov/data/datasets.html?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, openFDA has no plans on incorporating VAERS.

Here is the link to the JSON you're looking for: https://api.fda.gov/download.json

Comment: where in that json file is the vaers data?